# Java Sorting Error

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int z;
        int [] a = new int[5];
    a[0]=4;
    a[1]=8;
    a[2]=5;
    a[3]=1;
    a[4]=3;
    for(;;){
        z=0;
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){

    if(a[i-1]>a[i]){
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i-1]=a[i];
        a[i]=tmp;
        z++;

    }

    }
    if(z==0){
        break;
    }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}}
```

Hi. I have this problem. I want to sort array items, but result of this code is 1 1 1 1 3. I can't understand where is problem. 
Thanks you very much!

Comment: Attach a debugger and walk through the code - that is the only way you will be able to learn from this expereince. I seriously recommend it. Someone dumping the answer on you will deprive you of that opportunity.

Comment: But I think my code is correct, and doesn't have to work wrong (((

Comment: Look carefully at the code to swap two elements of the array.

Comment: don't think, debug it yourself and be sure like any other professional would

Comment: Again, just Google "[name of your IDE] debugging" and use that tool to walk, line by line, through your code.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the value of a[i-1] thus you lose it
So you have just to change this int tmp = a[i]; with this int tmp = a[i-1]; 
The whole code is :

public class MailClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int z;
        int [] a = new int[5];
    a[0]=4;
    a[1]=8;
    a[2]=5;
    a[3]=1;
    a[4]=3;
    for(;;){
        z=0;
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){

    if(a[i-1]>a[i]){
        int tmp = a[i-1];
        a[i-1]=a[i];
        a[i]=tmp;
        z++;

    }

    }
    if(z==0){
        break;
    }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Cannot understand the downvote. Though answer is poor, it seems to be correct